# CMake indicates compiler does not support flag but it does

Tags: c, cmake, compiler-warnings

I'm using CMake to configure the portable compilation of a C project and I wanted to check if the used compiler supports the various compilation flags I'm willing to use.

Suppose I have this simple C file `noinit.c` which uses a non-initialized variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i; // Uninitialized
    printf("%d\n", i+2);
    return 0;
}
```

I would like an error to be raised by the compiler, so I use the flags `-Wall -Werror`. This is my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1 FATAL_ERROR)

project(cmake_compiler_flag_test C)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

include(CheckCCompilerFlag)
list(APPEND COMPILER_FLAGS_TO_USE "-Wall" "-Werror")
foreach (FLAG IN LISTS COMPILER_FLAGS_TO_USE)
    # Check if the compiler supports the flag. The result of this test
    # is printed to STDOUT when calling `cmake`.
    check_c_compiler_flag(${FLAG} COMPILER_SUPPORTS_${FLAG})
    # Regardless of the test, force the usage of the flag anyway.
    string(APPEND CMAKE_C_FLAGS " ${FLAG}")
endforeach()

add_executable(noinit noinit.c)
```

When I call CMake, it says my compiler does not support `-Werror`.

```
> mkdir build
> cd build
> cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 9.1.0.9020039
-- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Wall
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Wall - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Werror
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Werror - Failed  # <-- NOTICE THE FAIL HERE!
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /some/path/to/cmake_compiler_flag_test/build
```

But when I call the compiler (which supports the flag), it actually works as expected and raises the error regarding the uninitialized variable:

```
> make
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/noinit.dir/noinit.c.o
/some/path/to/cmake_compiler_flag_test/noinit.c:5:20: error: variable 'i' is
      uninitialized when used here [-Werror,-Wuninitialized]
    printf("%d\n", i+2);
                   ^
/some/path/to/cmake_compiler_flag_test/noinit.c:4:10: note: initialize the
      variable 'i' to silence this warning
    int i; // Uninitialized
         ^
          = 0
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/noinit.dir/noinit.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/noinit.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Am I doing something wrong in my CMake configuration or is this a CMake bug?

Tools and their versions used for this test:

- macOS 10.13.4
- CMake 3.11.2
- compilers tested (both show the same issue):

  - Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)
  - gcc-8 (Homebrew GCC 8.1.0) 8.1.0

Comment: The `CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log` is somewhat revealing: `In file included from <built-in>:341:
<command line>:1:27: error: ISO C99 requires whitespace after the macro name [-Werror,-Wc99-extensions]
#define COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Werror 1`.

Comment: It appears your variable name creation (`COMPILER_SUPPORTS_${FLAG}`) fails, as there is a `-` in the name. You'll want to strip that hyphen from `${FLAG}` before appending, or find another way around it.

Comment: (The actual odd thing is that `-Wall` seems to succeed. Then again, invert the order of the two strings in your `list()` near the top, and both will fail.)

Comment: That was it! Adding `string(REPLACE "-" "" FLAG_NO_HYPHEN ${FLAG})` and using `check_c_compiler_flag(${FLAG} COMPILER_SUPPORTS_${FLAG_NO_HYPHEN})` works! Please write a full answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log` is somewhat revealing:

```
In file included from <built-in>:341: 
<command line>:1:27: error: ISO C99 requires whitespace after 
the macro name [-Werror,-Wc99-extensions] 
#define COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Werror 1

1 error generated.
```

It appears your variable name creation (`COMPILER_SUPPORTS_${FLAG}`) fails, as there is a hyphen, `-`, in the name. You'll want to strip that hyphen from `${FLAG}` before appending, or find another way around it.

As per your own suggestion, you could add the line

```
string(REPLACE "-" "" FLAG_NO_HYPHEN ${FLAG})
```

before the compiler flag test, and then use

```
check_c_compiler_flag(${FLAG} COMPILER_SUPPORTS_${FLAG_NO_HYPHEN})
```

instead.

---

The actual odd thing to me is that `-Wall` seems to succeed, which likely will have thrown you off (if both had failed, it's more obvious there's something amiss in `CMakeLists.txt`).
Inverting the order of the two flag strings in `list(...)` near the top will actually cause both tests to fail.

`CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log`, in this case, shows

```
In file included from <built-in>:341:
<command line>:1:27: warning: ISO C99 requires whitespace after the
macro name [-Wc99-extensions]
#define COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Wall 1

1 warning generated.
```

Here, it's only a warning, but with the reversed order, both tests become errors.

Perhaps someone knows why that is, and can comment on it. Or it's simply a bug in CMake.